# Trouble resizing the default image with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I want to be able to resize the default profile image I use with Paperclip. This is the code in my model:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :tiny => "25x25#",
    :thumbnail => "100x100#",
    :small  => "150x150>",
    :medium => "300x300>" },
    :default_url => "/images/default.png"
```

However, the default image doesn't get resized like the user submitted images do. How can I do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The solution I've been using is to specify the style for the default image:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
:styles => {
  :tiny => "25x25#",
  :thumbnail => "100x100#",
  :small  => "150x150>",
  :medium => "300x300>" },
  :default_url => "/images/default_:style.png"
```

Then create a default image for each style (eg: default_tiny.png that is 25x25px, etc...)

Hope that helps.

Comment: nice approach and very neat

Answer (score 0):

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
    :tiny => "25x25#",
    :thumbnail => "100x100#",
    :small  => "150x150>",
    :medium => "300x300>" },
    :default_url => "/images/default.png"
```

when you use paperclip for resizing purpose, you will have two options for resizing

1. # -> it crop your image with provided dimension
2. > -> it resize your image with provided dimension

I think in your case, your image is not match with your dimension.that's why it is not getting resized

Comment: huh? could you please explain this better.

Comment: for example your image size is 300x300 and you try to resize in 400X400.then it wont work

Comment: you realize I'm just talking about the default image, right? the image at /images/default.png