# Paperclip set default images for all different styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

So in my model I have different sizes for my avatar:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :styles => {
    :thumb => "60x60>",
    :small  => "80x80>",
    :medium => "140x140>",
    :large =>   "300x300>"},
  :default_url => "/images/default_avatar.png"
```

Now when I call `model_instance.avatar.url(:small)` it will return "/images/default_avatar.png" if there is no avatar. It will also return the same result for any style I choose.

I want to make the default images change upon change of style so that when I call `model_instance.avatar.url(:small)` it should return "/images/default_avatar_small.png" and if I call `model_instance.avatar.url(:large)` it should return "/images/default_avatar_large.png"

How can I make paperclip assign different default avatar for each style?

Comment: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987751/trouble-resizing-the-default-image-with-paperclip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `:style` can be included in the default url string which allows you to make it dynamic:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :styles => {
    :thumb => "60x60>",
    :small  => "80x80>",
    :medium => "140x140>",
    :large =>   "300x300>"},
  :default_url => "/images/default_avatar_:style.png"
```