# Ruby on rails gem paperclip How to generate missing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I uploaded a missing.png to public/images/ folder. But the the missing.png not showing correctly.
The website requires images/small/missing.png
So I guest I should generate the missing.png for thumb small medium large size.
What should I do?

Update 1:
I manually create a folder public/images/small and put missing.png inside the small folder. The website shows the missing.png. But What's is the correct way to generate all size of missing.png?

Comment: Maybe it could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987751/trouble-resizing-the-default-image-with-paperclip

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work for me. I change the model :default_url => "/images/missing_:style.png" It gives me <img src="/images/missing_medium.png" alt="Missing medium">

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your model:

```
 has_attached_file :image, styles: { :small => "150x150>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
```

Comment: I think you must move your images to assets/images instead of public/images, or change the default_url to "public/images/:style/missing.png".

Comment: Yes, I think you are right to move the folder. I move the missing.png to public/images folder. But I move missing.png to public/images/small folder to make the small missing.png work. Medium size still doesn't work.